# set/get Datepicker value ExtJS

Tags: extjs, datepicker, extjs4, sencha-architect

I'm using ExtJs 4 to create a calendar with Sencha Architect (Ext.menu.DatePicker).

But I have a problem with getters and setters.

This is my datepicker:

```
{
      xtype: 'datemenu',
      floating: false,
      height: 242,
      id: 'calendarT',
      width: 241
}
```

And later to get value I'm using .getValue() function:

```
console.log(Ext.getCmp('calendarT').getValue());
```

But firebug says: 'TypeError: Ext.getCmp(...).getValue is not a function'

With set is the same problem.

Any solution?

Thanks for all, Ivan.

UPDATE: my example is similar to this:[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5l8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved, very easy:

```
Ext.getCmp('calendarT').query('datepicker')[0].getValue());
```